# AmCharts: is there a way to enable zooming only by X axis on XYChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using amcharts 3 for xychart and I would like to disable possibility for user to zoom y axis, but still make it possible to zoom x axis by ChartCursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should set:

```
"hideYScrollbar":true
```

Full source:

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
     "type": "xy",
     "theme": "light",
     "marginRight": 80,
     "marginTop": 17,
     "hideYScrollbar":true,
     "dataProvider": [{
         "y": 10,
         "x": 14,
         "value": 59,
         "y2": -5,
         "x2": 0,
         "value2": 44
     }, {
         "y": 5,
         "x": 3,
         "value": 50,
         "y2": -15,
         "x2": -8,
         "value2": 12
     }, {
         "y": -10,
         "x": -3,
         "value": 19,
         "y2": -4,
         "x2": 6,
         "value2": 35
     }, {
         "y": -6,
         "x": 5,
         "value": 65,
         "y2": -5,
         "x2": -6,
         "value2": 168
     }, {
         "y": 15,
         "x": -4,
         "value": 92,
         "y2": -10,
         "x2": -8,
         "value2": 102
     }, {
         "y": 13,
         "x": 1,
         "value": 8,
         "y2": -2,
         "x2": -3,
         "value2": 41
     }, {
         "y": 1,
         "x": 6,
         "value": 35,
         "y2": 0,
         "x2": 1,
         "value2": 16
     }],
     "valueAxes": [{
         "position": "bottom",
         "axisAlpha": 0
     }, {
         "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
         "axisAlpha": 0,
         "position": "left"
     }],
     "startDuration": 1.5,
     "graphs": [{
         "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
         "bullet": "bubble",
         "lineAlpha": 0,
         "valueField": "value",
         "xField": "x",
         "yField": "y",
         "fillAlphas": 0,
         "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
         "maxBulletSize": 80

     }, {
         "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
         "bullet": "bubble",
         "lineAlpha": 0,
         "valueField": "value2",
         "xField": "x2",
         "yField": "y2",
         "fillAlphas": 0,
         "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
         "maxBulletSize": 80

     }],
     "marginLeft": 46,
     "marginBottom": 35,
     "chartScrollbar": {},
     "chartCursor": {},
     "balloon":{
      "fixedPosition":true
     },
     "export": {
         "enabled": true
     }
 });
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/cdd55aa9f4f761686a4027d6895263da